# htaccess blocking requests to /?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, security

I am getting a ton of bots or something hitting my site for URLs like: www.website.com/?how-much-does-a-ventolin-inhaler-cost-in-canada

I have no idea what they are, it doesn't resolve on anything to my site but it causing significant mysql overhead as my index has some heavy queries.

I can't seem to figure out how to stop these via htaccess because of the question mark...

I was thinking something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\?^
RewriteRule .*$ - [F,L]
```

But no dice.

Comment: Query strings are not part of the `REQUEST_URI`. This can indeed be done by checking the `QUERY_STRING` in the condition, but it may interfere with the way your site operates. Does your site have any URLs that need query strings?

Answer (score 0):

All values found after the "?" in the URL are called query string parameters. Does your entire website not use query string parameters? You may want to be careful before removing every request with a query string parameter, because that's a pretty common way of using the internet.

If you really want to strip them, the following code would work.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="" 
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

However, this just blocks all requests to your page that contain query parameters. Anyone could easily spam your page without any query parameters if they knew it caused an issue that would lead to a denial of service for you.

This whole issue sounds like there's a more systemic issue beneath - it shouldn't be causing you significant overhead for people who hit your default page.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you publish webstats or some similar information like top URLs, top referers, etc. As the symptoms suggests you are being targeted by search engine poisoning.